# Every Dropdown list have formopen codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

**i want to do is every dropdown list have submit example.
every list have formopen.
this is my sample code**

```
<?php $delete = form_open('maintenance/delete',array('name'=>'deleteCheckForm'));
        $active = form_open('maintenance/active',array('name'=>'deleteCheckForm'));
        $disable = form_open('maintenance/disable',array('name'=>'deleteCheckForm'));
?>

<table>
    <tr>
<?php foreach($sample as $list) { ?>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="type"></td>
    <td>name :<?php echo $list->name; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
    </tr>
</table>



<select onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="<?php echo $delete; ?>">delete</option>
        <option value="<?php echo $active; ?>">active</option>
        <option value="<?php echo $disable; ?>">disable</option>
    </select>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: what you are trying to do?

Comment: if i click active  the data will be edit. i want to do is every option have a action .

Comment: sample the option delete is for form_open (delete) ant the other one is form_open(active) and disable

Comment: please help me to do this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<body>
<?php echo form_open('', array('name'=>'deleteCheckForm'))?>
<table>
<?php foreach($sample as $list) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="type"></td>
        <td>name :<?php echo $list->name; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
<select onchange="this.form.action='<?php echo site_url('maintenance')?>/'+this.value;this.form.submit()">
    <option value="delete">delete</option>
    <option value="active">active</option>
    <option value="disable">disable</option>
</select>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the delete not linking

Comment: so, you may add one more option before delete, and make it the default selection,`<option value=""  selected>action</option>`

Comment: oh yeah :) how about the array ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one

first make your form outside of php tag

```
<form action="your_action" id="delete_frm" method="post"></form>
<form action="your_action" id="active_frm" method="post"></form>
<form action="your_action" id="diable_frm" method="post"></form>
```

then your select option will be like

```
<select id="select_form_post">
    <option value="delete">delete</option>
    <option value="active">active</option>
    <option value="disable">disable</option>
</select>
```

then your script will be like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/ 1.7.1/ jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#select_form_post").change(function(){
    var form_to_post=$(this).val();
    if(form_to_post=="delete")
    {
        $("#delete_frm").submit();
    }
    if(form_to_post=="active")
    {
        $("#active_frm").submit();
    }
    if(form_to_post=="disable")
    {
        $("#disable_frm").submit();
    }
});
</script>
```

please let me know if you need anything more.

Comment: how about my array sir ?